# Rememberable Password Formula

Tags: passwords, password-management

I was reading the comments under [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/206149/24064) and saw this comment

> Your answer to the question is basically to use a password formula, and there is already an answer that covers that option. Your example formula has a lot of flaws, and I would not recommend this formula at all if I was recommending formulas.

The upvoted answers on the related question where about 'password managers' Searching this site I found a related question [What is your way to create good passwords that can actually be remembered?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/662/24064) the majority of the top voted answers there focus on creating a single password.

If someone wants to depend on their mind rather a 'password manager' and they want to follow best practices they need a different password for each site, which implies some kind of Password Formula.

Additional best practices are to change passwords at least occasionally, like monthly or annually.

If I want to only use my mind to store my passwords, and I want a different password for each site, is there a good rememberable password formula?

Comment: The short answer is 'no'. If you are going to use site-specific passwords, then they also have to be temporal (time-based or time-limited) to account for when you need to change one site's password for one reason or another. So, you are down to doing something like, or the equivallent of, `Facebook mar-19 some kind of padding or mangling I will remember`.